# How to understand dimension of Keras Conv2D layer weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I tried to experiment with CNN pruning I was stopped right in the beginning because I couldn't explain the weight dimensions to myself.

The CNN has the following structure (exported from `model.layers()`):

1. `conv2d` (64 filters with filter dimension 5x5)
2. `max_pooling2d`
3. `dropout`
4. `conv2d` (128 filters with filter dimension 5x5)
5. `max_pooling2d`
6. `flatten`
7. `dense` (128 units)
8. `dense` (39 classes)

The corresponding weights have the following dimensions (from `.get_weights()`):

1. `conv2d`: shape(5,5,1,64)
2. `max_pooling2d`: shape(64,)
3. `dropout`: shape(5,5,64,128)
4. `conv2d`: shape(128,)
5. `max_pooling2d`: shape(6272,128)
6. `flatten`: shape(128,)
7. `dense`: shape(128,39)
8. `dense`: shape(39,)

Please have a look at the Conv2D layers and their parameters and dimensions. The first Conv2D layer (conv2d: shape(5,5,1,64)) seems to have an explainable number of weights: 5 x 5 (filter size) and 64 filters.

What is unclear to me is why the second Conv2D layer (conv2d: shape(128,)) only has 128 entries in the weights array. The dropout layer before (dropout: shape(5,5,64,128)) seems to have the weights dimensions I would expect the Con2D layer to have.

Comment: Dropout and max-pool layers have no weights, so something is wrong with your list of weights. I think you're having biases in your conv layers and you're not accounting for them properly

Comment: post the code,so that we could look what is wrong

Comment: You're right and I just found out what was wrong with my mapping from layer to weights. To get the weights, I did not as I described above use .get_weights() , but instead read the model_config I exported earlier and it seems I made a mistake there. Now that I used the get_weights(), the expected dimensions appear.

Comment: also note that convolution also applies biases (unless bias=False is specified) so second element in `get_weights()` list should be the biases of first convolution and so on.